# How to Invoke Method with class type parameters C#

Tags: c#, .net, oop, c#-4.0, reflection

I want to call my method via reflection, but my class uses a reference type value:

```
namespace XXX.Domain.XY.Products.Products.Myprovider {
public class ProductClass
{
    public void Save(Product entity)
   {

   }
}
```

How can I pass `MyEntity` by using below code? `Save` method has class type parameter.

```
Assembly loadedAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(dll);
//if (loadedAssembly.GetName().Name== "FFSNext.Domain")

Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom($"{binPath}FFSNext.Domain.dll");
Type t = asm.GetType("XXX.Domain.XY.Products.Products.Myprovider.ProductClass");
//Get and display the method.
MethodBase Mymethodbase = t.GetMethod("Save");
Console.Write("\nMymethodbase = " + Mymethodbase);

//Get the ParameterInfo array.
ParameterInfo[] Myarray = Mymethodbase.GetParameters();

Type testType = t;
object testInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(testType);

MethodInfo openMethod = testType.GetMethod("Save");

openMethod.Invoke(testInstance, new object[] { new Product() });
```

Comment: There's far too many unknowns in this code. What is `ProductClass`? What is `Product`? What isn't working right now? Do you have errors? etc. etc.

Comment: I suppose `MyClass` should be `ProductClass`, shouldn´t it? By the way: what do you mean by "class type parameter"? Your `Safe`-method expects an entity, and you want to provide a `Product`. How do those tow things relate to each other?

Comment: @HimBromBeere yes you are right. I updated it.

Comment: Your code should work as expected, if you have any errors there, probably your `Product` class is not inherited from `MyEntity` class...

Comment: @NaDeRStar I guess but it couldn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need a `Product` class and a `ProductClass` class:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Product(string Name)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
    }
}
```

(You can obviously customize your `Product` class with other properties and so on.)

and your `ProductClass` class:

```
public class ProductClass
{
    public void Save(Product value)
    {
        // Save your product
        Console.WriteLine("Save method called successfully with the product " + value.Name);
    }
}
```

Then you need to invoke your method like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    // The namespace of your ProductClass
    string NameSpace = "SomeNameSpace.SomeSecondaryNameSpace";

    Product toSave = new Product(Name:"myProduct");

    // Load your assembly. Where it is doesn't matter
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("Some Assembly Path");

    // Load your type with the namespace, as you already do
    Type productClass = assembly.GetType($"{NameSpace}.ProductClass");

    // Type.GetMethod returns a MethodInfo object and not MethodBase
    MethodInfo saveMethod = productClass.GetMethod("Save");

    // Create an instance of your ProductClass class
    object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(productClass);

    // Invoke your Save method with your instance and your product to save
    saveMethod.Invoke(instance, new object[] { toSave });

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

This code works fine for me... Do you have any errors with it?